# Caesars Cipher not understanding how to solve

Tags: javascript, encoding

I need help with my code. I am trying to approach the Caesar cipher problem, and from the readings I've done I feel like I am somewhat on the right track. I am new at coding so I still have a lot to learn in case this seems poorly written. What I was trying to do was to split the string into an array and check if each element of that array is a letter. If it is, then the letter will be transformed to a new letter using the **charCodeAt()** and **fromCharcode()** functions. I manage to do this separately with only one letter but then  mess it up when it comes in the loop. I would appreciate if anyone would give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong, or even if i am headed in the right direction. Thank you!

```
function rot13(str) {  

var splitArr = str.split('');  
var newArr = [ ];  

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){  
      if (isLetter(splitArr[i]) === true){  
        newArr = String.fromCharCode(splitArr.charCodeAt(splitArr.length[i]) + 13);  
    } else {  
        newArr.push(splitArr[i]);  
       }  
    }  
        return  newArr.join("");  
}

function isLetter(str) {  
return str.length === 1 && str.match(/[A-z]/i); //checks if its a letter  
}


// Change the inputs below to test  
rot13("AB? ...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you're fuzzy on the details.

First, `charCodeAt` works on strings, not arrays, so you don't have to split the string into an array first. As the name of the method indicates, you're asking for the character code *at* the given position in the string.

Second, `splitArr.length[i]` doesn't make sense - calling `.length` on an array returns a number, which you can't then turn around and subscript; e.g.   `['a','b','c'].length[i]` turns into `3[i]`.

Third, when doing the rot 13, you have to be sure to keep the result within the alphabet.  The char code for `A` is 65, and adding 13 gets you 78, which is `N`, as desired - great. But `N` is also supposed to turn back into `A`, and adding 13 to 78 gets you 91, which is a left bracket (`[`).

The usual approach is to subtract the character code of 'A' (or 'a' if it's lowercase), add 13, take the result *modulo* 26 (that is, the remainder after you divide by 26), and add that back to the character code of 'A'.

Here's a function ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8oagkLL/4/)) that will rot13 a single-character string. You should be able to modify it to do a string of any length:

```
var Acode = "A".charCodeAt(0);
var Zcode = "Z".charCodeAt(0);
var aCode = "a".charCodeAt(0);
var zCode = "z".charCodeAt(0);

function rot13singleChar(ch) {
  var code = ch.charCodeAt(0);
  if (code >= Acode && code <= Zcode) {
    code = (code - Acode + 13) % 26 + Acode;
  } else if (code >= aCode && code <= zCode) {
    code = (code - aCode + 13) % 26 + aCode;
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(code);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes total sense. I will try and implement the code and figure how to return the strings with the letters changed but special characters intact.